# Different between Jenkins build duration vs estimatedDuration vs timestamp

Tags: jenkins, continuous-deployment, cicd, jenkins-job-dsl

I like to find out the correct difference and what they mean between duration and estimatedDuration and timestamp in the Jenkins build details.

What I think is that timestamp refers to the time when the build commences. Duration is the  it takes for the build to be completed. estimatedDuration was the time estimated the build from when it starts to when it will end but I'm sure and I like to hear what others have to say.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out the difference?

Comment: I figured it out and what I said is actually correct.